Choppy sound with bluetooth speaker and pipewire
Since upgrading from KUbuntu 22.04 to 24.04, and having Pulseaudio replaced with Pipewire (why ? why ? why ?), my bluetooth speakers have not been working properly. It is difficult to describe it in English : the volume, general speed and tone are correct, but it sounds choppy, as if some sound fragments were not sent/dealt with at the required time, so that mini pauses will happen and at other times the sound will sort of catch up the delay.
The speaker is a M-1150BT by Muse. It is bound with A2DP profile and SBC codec (not SBC-XQ).
The Bluetooth dongle is a Belkin Components F5D5050 (050d:0121).
The pipewire configuration si standard, except for having pulse.min.quantum = 256/48000 in /etc/pipewire/pipewire-pulse.conf.d/minquantum.conf as a tentative fix to noise sometimes happening on my main sound card (seems to have worked).
